# How to save downloaded file to local folder?

Tags: c#, webclient

I want to store file which is coming from API, i have tried the below code but it is giving error.

```
string StrFileName = result.LabelDownload.Href;
string FilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();
string dir = string.Format("{0}{1:yyyy-MM}\\", FilePath, DateTime.Now);

   // Save the uploaded file.               
   if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
     Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadFile(StrFileName, dir);
```

Error: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
Inner Exception: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

how i can download file from web and store it my local folder? i need to save that path in database

Comment: This question has nothing to do with HTML or ASP.NET.

Comment: The second parameter is a *file* name, not a directory name

Answer (score 3):

The `WebClient.DownloadFile` method requires the filename where to download the file, not just the directory. So either pass just the filename and it will save the file to the apps directory or provide the fully qualified path.

```
string sourceFileName =   
result.LabelDownload.Href;
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();
string dir = string.Format("{0}{1:yyyy-MM}", filePath, DateTime.Now);

   // Save the uploaded file.               
   if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
     Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadFile(sourceFileName, Path.Combine(dir, sourceFileName));
```

The same goes for the source file. Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.8).

Also take a look at [c# naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) as local variables are usually lower case.

Comment: `DownloadFile` can work with relative file names too. The OP posted a dictionary name instead of a file name though

Comment: I would skip the final (escaped) backslash `\\ ` when composing the folder name, and let the following `Path.Combine` do the magic

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sure, I actually wanted to point out that the filename is needed but didn’t phrase it correctly

Comment: @GianPaolo missed to delete the slash, thanks. That’s why I used the Path.Combine

Answer (score 0):

I solve it,

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(StrFileName, dir + filenameWithoutPath);
```

before i wasn't added filename, so we need to add filename, in my case it is filenameWithoutPath, it is working now.

Comment: That's the wrong way to create an absolute path. Use `Path.Combine` instead, to avoid issues due to extra or missing backslashes. On the other hand, relative paths will work just fine. Simply specifying the filename will store the file in the current directory